# Quick Rejection: Binary division has 0 remainder?

Tags: math, binary

Is there a quick way for me to tell (quick rejection) whether a binary number when divided by another one has a remainder of 0 or not? I don't want to have to carry out the entire division. For example, dividing 1001 0110 1011 1110 by 11011. No carry is required.

This is for a networking project.

Comment: I don't think there are really any secret tricks to Mod 2 division... you just have to do the work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not in general.

Certain special cases can be checked quickly, like if the divisor is a power of two, but there are no shortcuts for the general problem.

Aside: although the shortcuts for special cases necessarily use the encoding of the number, whether or not a division produces a remainder is a property of the numbers involved, not their encodings.

Comment: Yes. In general having a number in binary makes this no easier, or harder, than general division. The only cases which are easier are powers of 2 (2,4,8,16,etc.)

Comment: thank you very much!!! Just trying to find out whether there could be a quick rejection for CRC checksum testing!

Comment: For computing a CRC efficiently use a table to handle a byte (or more) at a time.